# cannot load such file -- smarter_csv (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, smartercsv

I want to use `smarter_csv` gem, but when I write in my code `require "smarter_csv"` it gives me error message below:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- smarter_csv (LoadError)

When i try in irb:

```
001 >  require 'smarter_csv'
 => true
```

I tried `require "smarter_csv/smarter_csv.rb"` does not help!

How can i fix it?

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: I just tried, did not help

Comment: did you run `bundle install` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried this gem. It works perfectly fine.

Try:

Step 1 - Install Gem

```
$ gem install 'smarter_csv'
```

Step 2 - Create new ruby file test.rb

```
require 'smarter_csv'

data = SmarterCSV.process('./users.csv')
puts data
```

Step 3 - Make sure you have your CSV file ready

Step 4 - Run the script

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

Should work just fine